# Why pytesseract can't recognize this image

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

I am testing the pytesseract OCR on this image

[image]

but the result is always  30770.0 but I would have wanted this number : 997,70
FYI : this image has already been transformed :

```
img = img.convert('L')  # greyscale
img = img.resize((img.size[0] * 3, img.size[1] * 3), 1)
img = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img).enhance(5.0)
img = ImageOps.equalize(img)
img = ImageOps.invert(img)
```

Below the code :

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe'
img2 = "full_snap__1609584655.png"
numStr2 = pytesseract.image_to_string(img2, lang='eng',config='--psm 10 --oem 1 digits -c tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')
print('997,70 :',float(numStr2))
```

I have already tried to adjust the --psm parameter of the pytesseract function image_to_string but it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2):

My solution to the problem is morphological-transformation.

If you apply [erosion](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d61/tutorial_py_morphological_ops.html)

> the thickness or size of the foreground object decreases or simply white region decreases in the image. It is useful for removing small white noises (as we have seen in colorspace chapter), detach two connected objects etc.

```py
erd = cv2.erode(gry, None, iterations=1)
```

Result:

[image]

Now, if you read it:

```py
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(erd))
```

Result:

```
997 70€
```

Code:

---

```py
import cv2
import pytesseract

img = cv2.imread("R83OY.png")
h, w, c = img.shape
gry = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
erd = cv2.erode(gry, None, iterations=1)
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(erd))
```

**Possible Question:** Why do you set kernel to None?

If you initialize a kernel (i.e. (5, 5) ) and apply it to the image, result will be:

[image]

As you can see, applying kernel is not improving the result.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I'm trying to have a reliable OCR, I see that Pytesseract  is not really reliable because I have to take into account all of his mistakes in my code in particular cases. Is there another OCR more reliable in the open source place?

Comment: Please look at my updated code, I think you will agree that my new solution is the answer.

Comment: @Coco: There is no such thing as "reliable OCR" because input can be transformed in many ways, can be noisy, can have low contrast, can contain non-text content like images etc. But what you can try is to build a more robust OCR solution using preprocessing for your types of input like Ahx shows here (e.g. thin lined numbers like in your images). There's an interesting [guide on this in the tesseract documentation](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html) that also contains resources for further reading.

Comment: Private API's like google vision (you have to pay) promise to be more robust, it preprocess the image automatically.
But the handy way (the free ones) usually need you to make it robust for your special use.